# magento 2: override block Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category.php

Tags: magento2, overrides

How to override file `Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category` ?

In above file with one `$private` key available and its create issue to override.

I want to do modify `function _getItemsData()` from this file.

Code for i have done:

```
etc/di.xml
```

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category" type="Name\Module\Model\Layer\Filter\Category" />
</config>
```

Code for `Name\Module\Model\Layer\Filter\Category.php`

in construct i have to add **category** model,

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Name\Module\Model\Layer\Filter;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\DataProvider\Category as CategoryDataProvider;

/**
 * Layer category filter
 */
class Category extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category
{
    private $dataProvider;
    protected $categorys;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\ItemFactory $filterItemFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item\DataBuilder $itemDataBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\DataProvider\CategoryFactory $categoryDataProviderFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $categoryFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $filterItemFactory,
            $storeManager,
            $layer,
            $itemDataBuilder,
            $escaper,
            $data
        );

        $this->dataProvider = $categoryDataProviderFactory->create(['layer' => $this->getLayer()]);
        $this->categorys = $categoryFactory;
    }
    /**
     * Get data array for building category filter items
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $productCollection */
        $productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
        $optionsFacetedData = $productCollection->getFacetedData('category');
        $category = $this->dataProvider->getCategory();
        $categories = $category->getChildrenCategories();

        $collectionSize = $productCollection->getSize();
        //echo 'testes';exit;
        if ($category->getIsActive()) {
            foreach ($categories as $category) { 
                if ($category->getIsActive())
                {
                    $this->itemDataBuilder->addItemData(
                        $this->escaper->escapeHtml($category->getName()),
                        $category->getId(),
                        1//custom add count 
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->itemDataBuilder->build();
    }
}
```

After remove var folder and check in frontend,

```
Notice: Undefined variable: dataProvider in app/code/Name/Module/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php on line 28
        #0 /var/www/html/mayvillagetrading-com/app/code/Name/Module/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php(28): Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/var/www/html/m...', 28, Array)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a protected method and so **you cannot use plugins**, you can solve it by adding a **preference** in your `di.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    ...
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category" type="My\Module\Model\Layer\Filter\Category" />
    ...
</config>
```

And create a new class extending the previuous:

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Model\Layer\Filter;

class Category extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category {
    ...
    protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

It is more or less the same approach of Magento 1 rewrites.

**Optional:**

If I correctly understood what you need, you will also probably need to access the private variable `$dataProvider`.

Since it is a private variable you cannot access it, so the best option is to redefine your logic or **copy the whole class code** in your new one.

You class will extend `AbstractFilter` instead of the original `Category` class.

Your new class will look like this:

```
<?php
namespace My\Module\Model\Layer\Filter;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\AbstractFilter;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\DataProvider\Category as CategoryDataProvider;

/**
 * Layer category filter
 */
class Category extends AbstractFilter
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper
     */
    private $escaper;

    /**
     * @var CategoryDataProvider
     */
    private $dataProvider;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\ItemFactory $filterItemFactory
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item\DataBuilder $itemDataBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory $categoryFactory
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper
     * @param CategoryManagerFactory $categoryManager
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\ItemFactory $filterItemFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $layer,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item\DataBuilder $itemDataBuilder,
        \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\DataProvider\CategoryFactory $categoryDataProviderFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $filterItemFactory,
            $storeManager,
            $layer,
            $itemDataBuilder,
            $data
        );
        $this->escaper = $escaper;
        $this->_requestVar = 'cat';
        $this->dataProvider = $categoryDataProviderFactory->create(['layer' => $this->getLayer()]);
    }

    /**
     * Apply category filter to product collection
     *
     * @param   \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return  $this
     */
    public function apply(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $categoryId = $request->getParam($this->_requestVar) ?: $request->getParam('id');
        if (empty($categoryId)) {
            return $this;
        }

        $this->dataProvider->setCategoryId($categoryId);

        $category = $this->dataProvider->getCategory();

        $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection()->addCategoryFilter($category);

        if ($request->getParam('id') != $category->getId() && $this->dataProvider->isValid()) {
            $this->getLayer()->getState()->addFilter($this->_createItem($category->getName(), $categoryId));
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get filter value for reset current filter state
     *
     * @return mixed|null
     */
    public function getResetValue()
    {
        return $this->dataProvider->getResetValue();
    }

    /**
     * Get filter name
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return __('Category');
    }

    /**
     * Get data array for building category filter items
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function _getItemsData()
    {
        /** @var \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection $productCollection */
        $productCollection = $this->getLayer()->getProductCollection();
        $optionsFacetedData = $productCollection->getFacetedData('category');
        $category = $this->dataProvider->getCategory();
        $categories = $category->getChildrenCategories();

        $collectionSize = $productCollection->getSize();

        if ($category->getIsActive()) {
            foreach ($categories as $category) {
                if ($category->getIsActive()
                    && isset($optionsFacetedData[$category->getId()])
                    && $this->isOptionReducesResults($optionsFacetedData[$category->getId()]['count'], $collectionSize)
                ) {
                    $this->itemDataBuilder->addItemData(
                        $this->escaper->escapeHtml($category->getName()),
                        $category->getId(),
                        $optionsFacetedData[$category->getId()]['count']
                    );
                }
            }
        }
        return $this->itemDataBuilder->build();
    }
}
```

Then change the code you need to change.

**There is probably a best way to do it**, but we should know what you are going to do.

Comment: Its not working. i have try same as above.plz test on your site.

Comment: I just tested on my local installation and it seems to be correctly working. Try flushing your cache and clearing var/generation.

Comment: display error: Notice: Undefined property: Namespace\Module\Model\Layer\Filter\Category::$dataProvider in /app/code/Namespace/Module/Model/Layer/Filter/Category.php

Comment: $dataProvider is private because it comes form direct injection. You cannot access it from a subclass, you have to require it from your contructor and rebuild the logic.

Comment: plz show your full code in answer.

Comment: Just copy the whole class in your new class and extend AbstractFilter instead of \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Layer\Filter\Category.

Comment: same error are generate not working

Comment: i have to remove condition in getitemsdata and only keep category is active condition inside function

Comment: Thanks its working now for just copy the wholeclass in new class and extend abstractfilter.